# windows phone onenote light theme keyboard

Tags: keyboard, windows-phone, themes

I'm playing around with windows phone development and an app that I'm prototyping would really benefit from forcing a light theme. Just like OneNote app does. And now I'm wondering, how guys from OneNote team do this?!

I know there is this amazing [Theme Manager](https://github.com/jeffwilcox/wp-thememanager) by Jeff Wilcox, but he writes that it's not possible to override/force keyboard look!

But it works in OneNote... How do they do this?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done with the current API.

Comment: Yep. The question though is how OneNote team does this.

Comment: But if anyone knew that, the answer wouldn't be "it can't be done" and it would be "it can be done with this". Besides, OneNote team is a part of Microsoft. Nokia, Microsoft and some third party developers have access to some features that ordinary developers don't.